# wifi authentication failed for hosted network

Tags: authentication, wifi

I have connected to the internet through a modem named QUBEE which shows as the connection 'Ethernet 2'. However, I have a tab and kindle fire. so, I decided to create a virtual network or hosted network in my laptop. So, I created a hosted network with a numeric pass key (8-digits). The authentication type is WPA2-Personal. I shared the net of Ethernet 2 with it. However, i tried with both my tab and kindle fire, but it shows 'Authentication problem'.
Both of the kindle fire and tab remains in 'Obtaining IP address...' state a lot of time.
One thing I noticed that, when the device is not connected to the virtual network, its network strength remains strong. but it tries to connect, it becomes poor.

Another thing is that the authentication type of that recognize by both tab and kindle fire is WPA2 PSK. where the laptop has WPA2-Personal.

My laptop configuration is i5@2.5GHz, Windows 8.1, RAM: 6.00GB, Lenovo G480.

Thanks in advance for trying to help me.